# Android Long pressed button Context menu

Tags: android, button, menu, android-context, ringtone

I have this method to start a notification. But now I would like to bind it to the long press of the button Context menu. How can I do?

```
public void ringtone(){
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu  
    return true;  
}  
@Override  
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    switch (item.getItemId()) {  
        case R.id.List1:  
             //List1 is a button in menu.xml
             //it is the button you want to bind the method to
             //call the function ringtone() fom here
             ringtone();
          default:  
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
    }  
}
```

Assuming that you have already made a ContextMenu and have a button in it with

```
android:id="@+id/List1"
```